# Unable to insert the role or Update the tab index dynamically for mydatepicker

Tags: html, angular, accessibility, tabindex

Issue:
We are getting 49 errors when we run the ARCTOOL KIT
[image]

I want to update either the role for each of the "td" in the calendar or need to update the tab index to "-1"

The dynamic code which I am using:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  var allTDElements = document.getElementsByClassName("caltable")[0].getElementsByTagName("td")

  for (var i = 0; i < allTDElements.length - 1; i++) {
    allTDElements[i].attributes['tabindex']['value'] = "-1";
    allTDElements[i].setAttribute("role", "button");
  }
}
```

The code is running fine but the values are not reflecting in the component. Can you please help me on how can I update either the role or tab index value

Comment: I'm using Angular 7+ and mydatepicker library, these errors i'm getting when I run the ARC toolkit

Comment: use `setAttribute` for the `tabindex` as well, `allTDElements[i].setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");` or use `allTDElements[i].attributes['tabindex'] = "-1";`, there is no such thing as `allTDElements[i].attributes['tabindex']['value'] = "-1";` so it will not set anything useful, but instead will create the "value" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the role after the element has been created in the DOM. The role isn't made to be modified dynamically.
In most (if not all) browsers, the change won't be reflected in the accessibility tree, and hance, won't be taken into account by screen readers and other assistive tools.
You must add the role attribute directly when creating the element. Otherwise your only solution is to remove it from the DOM and add it again.

For tabindex, using the setAttribute method, it should work. It is perfectly allowed to switch from 0 to -1 and vice-versa.